# How change default search setting from "all words" to "any words"?

Tags: joomla-3.x, search, com-search

By default, in the Search module of Joomla, "all words" is selected by default. I want "any words" to be selected by default.

Does anyone know where I have to make the changes in files and the location of files?

I have searched the "com_search" folder in both the component and the module folders, but was not able to find anything useful.

Comment: This page seems to be abandoned. Did one of the answers resolve your question?  Please progress this page to an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the `view.html.php` file located here: `components/com_search/views/search/view.html.php`

Navigate to line 102 where you will find `COM_SEARCH_ALL_WORDS`. Put that whole line below the `COM_SEARCH_ANY_WORDS` line.

This will effectively change the default search option to be "any words".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This option is not available in Search component configuration but is available per menu item. Create `Search Form or Search Results` menu item and set `Search For` option in `Options` tab.